# NAudio Resampling in 2016?

Tags: naudio, codec, resampling

http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-to-resample-audio-with-naudio.html?m=1

I followed that link to make some simple code for downmixing an 8KHz WAV audio to 4100KHz.
Some of those samples work and make recognizable output, others make only noise/groaning.
I do not think it is the NAudio code itself, but how the codecs work.
Can someone point me to sample code that shows how to enumerate codecs installed in Windows 10,
or enumerate what comes with NAudio, so the various output types can be compared?
I looked at IResampler but am missing something...

This does not make recognizable sound:

```
using ( var waveFileReader = new AudioFileReader( FileNameIn ) )
{
    var outFormat = WaveFormat.CreateIeeeFloatWaveFormat( 4100 , waveFileReader.WaveFormat.Channels );
    using ( var resamplerCurrent = new MediaFoundationResampler( waveFileReader , outFormat ) )
    {
        resamplerCurrent.ResamplerQuality = 60;
        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile( tmpFile , resamplerCurrent );
    }
}
```

These examples both make recognizable sound:

```
using ( var waveFileReader = new AudioFileReader( FileNameIn ) )
{
    var outFormat = new WaveFormat( 4100 , waveFileReader.WaveFormat.Channels );
    using ( var resamplerCurrent = new MediaFoundationResampler( waveFileReader , outFormat ) )
    {
        resamplerCurrent.ResamplerQuality = 60;
        WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile( tmpFile , resamplerCurrent );
    }
}
using ( var waveFileReader = new AudioFileReader( FileNameIn ) )
{
    var resamplerCurrent = new WdlResamplingSampleProvider( waveFileReader , 4100 );
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16( tmpFile , resamplerCurrent );
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: when you say "this does not", what is the problem? Do you get an error? Corrupt audio?

Comment: @MarkHeath - Sorry, I added more clarity to the post. The output for the 2nd and 3rd do not sound like the original waveform at all. Thanks.

Comment: your third code snippet works fine for me. What sort of input are you using. Obviously with a very low sample rate like 4100 the audio will lose some clarity, but shouldn't sound like white noice.

Comment: @MarkHeath, sound sample is https://1drv.ms/u/s!An4PjBo4DvVxgRqctDGzmaelQknI I am restating the problem a bit in the main ask as well. thanks.

Comment: can you try the non-working example with a WavFileReader instead of AudioFileReader?

Comment: @MarkHeath, I did just replace it with WaveFileReader. The output is the same. Thanks.